# Solving bilinear systems on a limited domain

Tags: numerical-methods, nonlinear-system, bilinear-form

Given a diagonal matrix $A$ with all entries $A_{i,i}\in(0,1)$ and trace equal to one

$$
A\in \mathbb{R}^{k \times k}
$$

and a second matrix

$$ 
B\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k},\,\,\,\,\,\,n\geq k,\,\,\,\,\,\,     B_{i,j}\in[0,1) 
$$

I am looking for any kind of theory studying the solutions of the system

$$
c = BAB^t ,\,\,\,c\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}
$$

for fixed $c$, where the known parameters are the matrix $A$, and the matrix $c$, while $B$ is unknown.

My hope is that something related to the geometric properties of the bilinear forms can help in some way, but also numerical approaches are welcome!

Thanks

Comment: There is a dimension mismatch for $n\ne 0$.

Comment: ..I can't find it

Comment: $c$ is a vector $BAB^t$ is a $n\times n$ matrix

Comment: You're right, edited. Thanks!

Comment: Have you heard of spectral/eigenvalue decomposition?

Comment: Yes, that was my first idea: to perform spectral decomposition of c, and "hope" the eigenvalues to coincide with the diagonal elements of A..but it is not the case unfortunately; so for this I am evaluating numerical methods..

Comment: the eigenvalues of $C$ need not be the diagonal of $A$. But they need to be positive...

Comment: I know that I can represent $c = ODO^t$ (eigenvalue decomposition), and I also think that in this case B and O might be in some kind related by an isometry..but it is impossible to get the right one, I think..

Comment: You could write $D = D^{1/2} A^{-1/2} A  A^{-1/2} D^{1/2}$.

Comment: Great, from this I can get one decomposition of the form $BAB^t$, setting $B=OD^{1/2}A^{-1/2}$.
It is not unique, but without further conditions we can't expect uniqueness.